# CoreData model with nested object relationships as a datasource?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

I have a very simple data model that consists of 2 objects — a `Section` and an `Item`. Each `Section` has a to-many child relationship to other `Section` objects as well as a to-one parent relationship with another `Section` object. Every section has a to-many relationship to `Item` objects.

[image: data model]

Structure aside, some `Section` objects have no `Item` objects, and others (at the bottom of the hierarchy) have no `Section` child objects.

I want to create a tableview that will use `Section` objects to create the section headers, and then display the `Item` objects as tableViewCells that are a part of that `Section`. I also want table headers to appear if the `Section` has no `Items`, because seeing the hierarchy is important.

Given a random `Section` object, how would I go about fetching and displaying this data? Do I need to create a nested loop that flattens the data in an array, or is there some awesome way to leverage predicates and `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: How do you want the `Item` objects sorted. Since they only have a single `text` attribute do you want them sorted on that? Do you want the sorted on the `Section.ID` or `Section.name` and then text?

Comment: I just simplified the model for this example, `Item` objects also have an ID.

Comment: You building a table of `Item` object here. Therefore, to answer your question, I would need to know on what key you want the objects sorted in the table.

Comment: Sorted by their respective `Section` ID, and then `Item` ID, which isn't included in the screenshot, oops.

Answer (score 0):

I would build your NSFetchedResultsController with a sort descriptor that sorts the items by the section's ID.

Something like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"section.ID" ascending:YES];
```

This will give your NSFetchedResultsController all the correct items grouped by section. Then you just need to flesh out your table view datasource and delegate accordingly.

Comment: How would I build the predicate in that case? Wanting to fetch all items of given `Section` as well as all items from child sections.

Comment: In my example you would grab all items in all sections, they would be sorted (visually in the table, and within the NSFRC) by the section. You wouldn't need a predicate in this case, just set the NSFRC entity and grab them all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your fetch entity to `Item`
2. Provide the fetch two sort descriptors. The first should sort on `section.ID` and the second should sort on `id`. That will return an array of `Item` objects sorted first by section and then by their own `id` attribute.
3. When initializing the fetched result controller, set the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter to `section.ID`. That will cause the section names to display as the `Section.ID` values.

That should give you a table like this:

```
Section.ID
    Item.ID
    Item.ID
    Item.ID
Section.ID
    Item.ID
.... and so on.
```